# How can I disable livewire dev tools on production environment?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I have a laravel 10 project that used livewire 3.

When I was on development I used Google Chrome devtools.

Today I deploy it on a local server and I turn the APP_ENV variable into production.

It works fine but I can see that the livewire devtools is still running so anyone can access the components and its data.

I wrongly thought it was handled by the value of the APP_ENV variable like the debugbar package.

Do you know if there is a way to disable it?

I did some research and found a few people had this problem but they never received any answers...

I'm surprised livewire didn't think of that.

Comment: The Chrome dev tools are a plugin to the browser, and it reads the public properties which are always exposed in JavaScript anyways. Don't think you can disable it for any environment. This is why it's important that you never add sensitive data as public props.

Comment: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/security "any parameters passed to Livewire actions are mutable on the client and should be treated as un-trusted user input"

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess you may be referring to Livewire Dev Tools, the chrome extension. It will likely be able to detect Livewire however it normally does, whether the site is in production or not as there are trails of Livewire in the code the application renders due to Hydration and such.

Comment: Ok I thought it was possible like Vue devtools...